# Does Google support JSON-LD for Products yet?

Tags: google-search, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

Does anyone know if Google supports JSON-LD for Products yet? This is from their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/schema-org):

> Google is in the process of adding JSON-LD support to more
>   markup-powered features. So far, JSON-LD is supported for all
>   Knowledge Graph features, sitelink search boxes, Event Rich Snippets,
>   and Recipe Rich Snippets; Google recommends the use of JSON-LD for
>   those features. For the remaining Rich Snippets types and breadcrumbs,
>   Google recommends the use of microdata or RDFa.

That page hasn't been updated since July 27, 2015.

If you look at their [examples for Products](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products), they show JSON-LD examples, but I'm not sure if this is just an example or if they are actually saying this format is now supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this (https://plus.google.com/+JohnMueller/posts/5ivUfWzdHX4), Google supports JSON-LD for Products and Reviews metadata markup