# Google Rich Card product JSON-LD no detected

Tags: google-search-console, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I was using structured data on on the products and I had not any error when I used it. More or less a month ago I changed structured data for JSON-LD. These change on the Goole Search console does not appear but it detect I stoped use structured data.

Here there is a real JSON-LD (is not proof) of one product:

```
 <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Cumlaude Sunlaude Cover Ip-30 10 G.",
  "image": "https://farmaciaribera.es/media/catalog/product/p/l/pl_1_1_9743.jpg",
  "description": "Cumlaude Sunlaude Compacto SPF 30 est&aacute; indicado para la protecci&oacute;n solar del rostro, ayuda a corregir las imperfecciones cut&aacute;neas actuando como un compacto maquillaje de alta protecci&oacute;n solar. Est&aacute; especialmente indicado para pieles con manchas (cloasma,",
  "sku": "200089",
  "brand": {
    "@type": "Thing",
    "name": "Dermofarm"
  },
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "bestRating": 10,
    "worstRating": 9,
    "ratingValue": 10,
    "reviewCount": 352
  },
  "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "priceCurrency": "EUR",
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "price": "21.22"
  }
}
```

And here you can see how [Tensting tool data structured](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/?hl=es#url=https%3A%2F%2Ffarmaciaribera.es%2Fcumlaude-sunlaude-cover-ip-30-10-g%2F) detect the product without any problem.

Also I have looking for information on Stack Overflow, in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458700/does-google-support-json-ld-for-products-yet) is confirmed Google detect product rich cards.

Comment: So your only problem is that Google Search Console does not detect it, correct?

Comment: [Cross-post](http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/137823/5949)